# Incrond Monitor NFS mounts?

Tags: linux, bash, nfs

I am having issues with incrond IN_CREATE option. I am able to successfully monitor the directory created in a specific folder which are locally created. But incrond is not able to monitor NFS mounted directories.

I have added an cifs NFS mount /mnt/DIR which is added to incrontab. Do you know why it is not able to monitor changes under /mnt/DIR?.

Thanks,

Comment: Has anyone ever came across this kind of issue?.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because there is no inotify support in NFS.

IOW, there is nothing in the NFS protocol which allows a client to specify some kind of interest in some file/directory, nor does the NFS protocol support the server pushing such notifications back to the client.

Comment: Thank You janneb for your reply. Is there Any other implementation available for watching NFS shared DIRs?.

Comment: I suppose you could fallback to polling if notification isn't available. Remember to make the poll interval configurable and/or possible to disable, otherwise admins running busy NFS servers will hate you.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a link on how to implement polling?.

Comment: Can this work on NAS Storage if it is mounted like a directory on a server?